# php json decode ingnore duplicate value

Tags: php, json

Php json decode, how to ingore duplicate value? in my case, if `$data->a` and `$data->b` are duplicate, only print the first appear value.

```
[
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"content1"},
{"a":"1","b":"3","c":"content2"},//print
{"a":"1","b":"3","c":"content3"},//duplicate "a":"1","b":"3", do not print
{"a":"2","b":"1","c":"content4"},
{"a":"2","b":"2","c":"content5"},//print
{"a":"2","b":"2","c":"content6"},//duplicate "a":"2","b":"2", do not print
{"a":"2","b":"3","c":"content7"}
]
```

This is not an easy `array_unique()` could work, ask for a help, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.php.net/array_filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hash array!

```
$tmp=json_decode($input);
$data=array();
foreach ($tmp as $item) {
  $idx=$item->a."::".$item->b;
  if (!isset($data[$idx])) $data[$idx]=$item;
}
$data=array_values($data);
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but `for ($tmp as $item) {` should be `foreach ($tmp as $item) {`